# Count giving wrong results in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

I am getting incorrect count from a query ran inside a stored procedure.
When we run the same query ( after hard-coding the values of table name and schema name ) it gives the correct result.

Preliminary analysis , hints the fact that the query run inside the stored procedure is for some reason ignoring the second filter ( i.e where ... and ... , the second part is being ignored ).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dev.gp_count (tablename VARCHAR(256))
AS
$$ DECLARE schema_name VARCHAR(64);

table_name VARCHAR(128);

check_count_1 INT;

check_count_2 INT;

BEGIN 

schema_name:= SPLIT_PART(tablename,'.',1);

table_name:= SPLIT_PART(tablename,'.',2);

check_count_1 := (select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = schema_name and table_name like '%' + table_name +'%');
raise info 'check_count_1 - %',check_count_1;

end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

And calling the above procedure as-

```
call dev.gp_count ('dev.gp_test1');
```

The result obtained from stored procedure is  - 
    Warnings:
    check_count_1 - 925

If we run the same query after substituting the values for table name and schema  then -

```
select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'dev' and table_name like '%gp_test1%';
```

*RESULT -*

```
count
3
```

Now investigating the issue further -

The count obtained from stored procedure is same as the count obtained from this query -

```
select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'dev';
```

*RESULT-*

```
count
925
```

**My Guess -**

So this hints that , maybe inside stored procedure the second filter condition is being ignored.

Besides helping me with other alternatives , please do help me find the reason behind this anomaly too .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some common roots, they are very different database products

Comment: I am using PLPGSQL  as language (in Postgresql ) for Stored-procedure and executing it on Redshift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem lies in 1) your string concatenation and 2) use of `table_name` as a variable:

```
check_count_1 := (select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = schema_name and table_name like '%' + table_name +'%');
```

PostgreSQL string concatenation uses `||`, so it should look like this:

```
check_count_1 := (select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = schema_name and table_name like '%' || table_name || '%');
```

Try changing it to look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE gp_count (tablename VARCHAR(256))
AS
$$ DECLARE
schema_name VARCHAR(64);
table_name1 VARCHAR(128);
check_count_1 INT;
check_count_2 INT;

BEGIN 
schema_name:= SPLIT_PART(tablename,'.',1);
table_name1:= SPLIT_PART(tablename,'.',2);

check_count_1 := (select count(*) from information_schema.tables f where table_schema = schema_name and f.table_name like '%' || table_name1 || '%');

raise info 'check_count_1 - %',check_count_1;

end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing !

Comment: Thanks @richyen, It worked like a charm.  Just an FYI - PostgreSQL does support concatenation with + or || . Both the options work.